# trying to add variable for div id. is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to use variable inside body. just see below sample code

```
<body>
 <div class="demo">
     <script>
     var count = 4;
      for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
          var varSlid = "A"+i;
          $('.demo').append('<div id= varSlid ></div></br>');
      }
     </script>
</div>
</body>
```

but it is throwing errors. please check and tell me where the error is?

Comment: This is not a valid javascript declaration. What exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: @user399426 - You can format the code blocks in your posts by indenting them by 4 spaces.

Comment: How about saying what the error message is?

Comment: You could try telling us what the errors you are getting are. Or are we supposed to guess?

Comment: welcome to SO.  You have some great answers below.  If any of them helped you or answered your question you should upvote it and/or set it as the accepted answer. This reward people for answering your question and you both get a little bit of rep in the process.

Answer (score 7):

Try This

```
var varSlid = "A"+i;
          $('.demo').append('<div id= ' + varSlid  + '></div></br>');
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is that *.demo* hasn't finished parsing yet, so you shouldn't be attempting to manipulate it.  This can cause serious issues in older versions of IE (["operation aborted"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/preventing-operation-aborted-scenarios), anyone?).  Move the script to just outside the `<div>` tag:

```
<body>
<div class="demo">
</div>
<script>
     var count = 4;
      for(var i=1;i<=count;i++){
          var varSlid = "A"+i;
          $('.demo').append('<div id='+varSlid+'></div><br/>');
      }
</script>
</body>
```

As others have pointed out, you also need the quotation marks to work the variable into your HTML string, although this wouldn't have caused any errors  - you would just end up with a bunch of elements all with the same id ("varSlid").

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's my lack of jQuery-fu... but shouldn't `</br>` be `<br/>`?

Also, you shouldn't create 4 elements `<div id= varSlid >` since the `id` attribute should be unique.

**Edit:** You probably intended to use the value of the variable `varSlid` as the `id` attribute, but rit now it's part of a hardcoded string literal. You'd want to something more like:

```
$('.demo').append('<div id="'+varSlid+"'></div><br/>');
```

Comment: the varSlid is supposed to assign a new value in every loop. The problem is its been used as a regular string not as a variable

Comment: Thanks, I missed that! this is what I get when I answer SO questions before drinking some coffee in the morning ;)

Comment: thanks all. its working fine.. I will implement your valuable suggestions

Comment: @user399426 - ... if it's working fine then you should perhaps accept an answer? If you usd a solution not present in the answers, you can write your own answer and accept it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$('.demo').append($('div').attr('id', varSlid)).append('<br/>');
```

Also wrap this entire function in `on dom ready` like

```
$(function(){
    //your code here...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change: `$('.demo').append('<div id= varSlid ></div></br>');` 
to: `$('.demo').append('<div id=' + varSlid + ' ></div></br>');`

Answer (score 0):

It's : `$('.demo').append('<div id="' + varSlid + '"></div></br>');`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not real clear on the OP's original question, but this fits the title.

HTML5 has a data-* attribute, where the * represents your data.  I've had luck with this passing Web.py (python) variables from the templator to js functions.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!--declare we are using HTML5-->
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    var jsVersionData = ''; //create a global variable for example simplicity
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="stored-variable" data-stored="7">
    <script> 
      jsVersonData =  document.getElementById("stored-variable");  //get the variable from the div
    </script>  
  </div>

  <script>
    var myStr = jsVersonData.dataset.stored;  // the variable
    var myInt = Number(myStr);                // convert the variable to int
    alert(myInt + 1);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```